# Unable to swap scam token on uniswap but you can transfer a coin

Tags: tokens, uniswap

I put money in a scam token on the ethereum blockchain, and when I wanted to withdraw it, the transaction is constantly canceled and the error "Replacement failed" comes out. You can't make a swap, but you can transfer, but maybe you can transfer to another coin and then make a swap?

There is a large amount on the balance right now, if someone can help me withdraw it, I will thank you 50% (~$9000)

Token: 0xe92071aB44d24D3272E61569b26828B876f530e4

Comment: You can try searching the scam contract source for bugs, but usually scammers are good and they won't make silly mistakes.